# Why is "HTTP:..." a valid line of PHP code?

Tags: php

In my PHP script, `http://www.google.com` is a valid line of code... why?

```
<?php

http://www.google.com

?>
```

This doesn't produce an error.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`http:` creates a [goto](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php) target label, and the rest is commented out by `//`

Comment: Beware of the [mad velociraptor](http://php.net/manual/en/images/0baa1b9fae6aec55bbb73037f3016001-xkcd-goto.png) after using `goto`.